# Perl Script to Grep Directory For String and Print

Tags: linux, bash, perl, grep

I would like to create a perl or bash script that will read keyboard input and assign a variable, perform a fixed string grep recursively within the current directory filled with Snort logs, and then automatically tcpdump the matched files, grep its output, and print the specified lines to the terminal. Does anyone have a good idea of how this should work?

Here is an example of the methodology I want from the script:

step 1: Read keyboard input and assign it to variable named string.

step 2 command: grep -Fr "$string"

step 2 output: snort.log.1470609906 matches

step 3 command: tcpdump -r snort.log.1470609906 | grep -F "$string" C-10

step 3 output:

[Snort log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzFjb.jpg)

Comment: Why Perl? Why not just use grep?

Comment: Trying to automate the process. I want to be able to type something like perl grep.pl "google.com" and have everything work behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some bash code that does that:

```
s="google.com"
grep -Frl "$s" | \
    while IFS= read -r x; do
        tcpdump -r "$x" | grep -F "$s" -C10
    done
```

Comment: Thanks very much redneb. Is there a way to make "google.com" a variable based on input prior to grepping?

Comment: I meant a variable assigned from keyboard input. I tried the following but it seems as though its trying to read the string entered as the file name:        #!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter fixed string to search: " string

grep -Frl "$string" | \
 while IFS = read -r x; do
  tcpdump -r "$x" grep -F "$string" -C 10
 done

Comment: You can say `s="$1"` at the beginning of the script. You can then pass the string as a command line argument to script where you saved the above code. If you want to read it from the stdin, replace the first line with `IFS= read -r s`.

Comment: Thanks much, redneb.

Comment: Done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

idk about perl but you can do it easily enough just in shell:

```
str="google.com"
find . -type f -name 'snort.log.*' -exec grep -FlZ "$str" {} + |
xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'tcpdump -r "{}" | grep -F '"$str"' -C10'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed Ed. Thanks!